# How to automatically direct print statements' outputs to a file in python?

Tags: python, logging, output

I have a python script, it contains `print` statements here and there for debugging purposes. Now I find it hard to read them in console. Does python have any libraries which will automatically direct all `print` statements' outputs to a specified text file? I use Windows 7 by the way, not Linux. I also **don't run** my scripts from command line.

So what I want is something like below:

```
import logger_module

log_file = "log.txt"
logger_module.activate_logging(log_file)

print "blablabla"
```

When I run the script above, I should see **"blablabla"** in `log.txt` file.

Comment: How about using redirection? `python script_name.py > output.txt`

Comment: Redirection works on windows 7

Comment: You might want to use the [`logging` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html).

Comment: But I want to run the script inside the script, not from command line.

Comment: @Nabla please explain how to use logging module in this case.

Comment: @alwbtc Make `logging.log` calls instead of prints, this wasn't meant solve your exact problem, but it seems appropriate for debugging

Comment: `run the script inside the script` ? Do you mean `subprocess` ?

Comment: No, I mean open the script with IDLE, then push run button on toolbar

Comment: The longer but probably better approach would be to convince the maintainers of that code to use the `logging` package.

Comment: Why is is using `logging` module better than Madison May's answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the closest you'll get:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('file', 'w')
print 'test' # prints test to file
```

If you'd like to write to multiple locations, you can use the following.  Any object with a write method can be assigned to sys.stdout in python.

```
import sys

class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self, *files):
        self.files = files

    def write(self, obj):
        for f in self.files:
            f.write(obj)

f = open('file', 'w')
sys.stdout = Logger(f, sys.stdout)

print "Python Magic"
```

Comment: Great. Could you please show how to write both to console and file? Because your answer just writes to file.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but I didn't mean multiple files, I wanted to to say, how to write both to a file and to the shell window?

Comment: That code should work for that purpose.  The shell window is more or less a "file" in the sense that you can write to it.  Give it a go and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Sir, thank you. Do big python software projects handle loggings this way?